# Django 1.9 tutorial __str__ () not working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.9

I am trying Django 1.9 tutorial with Win 10 os and Python 3.5 and Django version is 1.9. I have successfully created and stored values in "Question" and "Choice". After this when i have changed polls/model.py with `__str__()` as per tutorial [django tutorial 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/). I am getting this error:

```
>>> from polls.models import Question, Choice
>>> Question.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\newenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.py", line 69, in handle
    self.run_shell(shell=options['interface'])
  File "C:\newenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.py", line 61, in run_shell
    raise ImportError
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\newenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 237, in __repr__
    return repr(data)
  File "C:\newenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 459, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
  File "C:\newenv\mysite_new\polls\models.py", line 8, in __str__
    return self.question_text
AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'question_text'
```

my polls\models.py is:

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Comment: Well, does your Question class has an attribute `question_text`?

Comment: yes i have followed all steps of tutorial. when i changed my models.py with tutorials code it displays this error.

Comment: Can you show your full models?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You most likely do not have `question_text` field in your Question model. You may have deleted it when you added the `__str__` method definition.

Check that you have this:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200) # <--- Double check you have this

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

Comment: ya , i made mistake. i have deleted class Question's definition and only place _str_ function. Thank you very much.!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the Django documentation, then it is some typo at your end. Just redo the model part and run the makemigration and migrate cmd. It should work.
I faced the same issue and then I just copied and pasted the code from Django documentation and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
def __repr__ (self):
    return self.title
```

restart the shell/session.

then check.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same problem but then I checked I forget to adddouble inverted comma instead of single `_` in `__str__`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are getting the error because you don't have proper indentation. I got the same error when I didn't have proper indentation. Now it's correct. Inside the class you should declare the function as following:

```
class Position(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).